# Python: scraping results of webpage of which results are generated server-side

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm fairly new to Python so excuse me if the problem isn't clear or if the answer is obvious. 
I want to scrape the web page http://jassa.fr/. I generated some random input (sequences) and see how it holds against my own data. I tried scraping the page using selenium but the HTML of the webpage doesn't use any id's, and I don't know how to navigate through the DOM without using id's ([impossible with selenium?](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/)). 
Does anyone have any ideas for me how to tackle this problem, especially regarding that I want to scrape the results which are generated server side?

Thanks in advance!

[edit]
Thanks for the quick response!
How do I access this text area using selenium: 
< textarea style="border:1px solid #999999;" tabindex="1" name="sequence" cols="70" rows="4" onfocus="if(this.value=='Type or paste your sequence')this.value='';">Type or paste your sequence

Comment: You should explain better, your question like that is too broad

Comment: You provided a link to webpage - it's always a good thing ;) However: 1) try to say exactly what you want to get 2) try to show some code what you tried - even if it throws an error - just include error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** After clarification that you need to access `<textarea>` with the name `sequence` I suggest using `find_element_by_name`, see [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) for more details on selecting elements in Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "http://jassa.fr/"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
form = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("form")
sequence = form.find_element_by_name("sequence")
sequence.clear()
sequence.send_keys("ATTTAATTTA")
form.submit()
```

---

Selenium has ability to navigate the tree and select elements not only by ID but also by class, tag name, link text and so on (see [the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html)), but I found myself more comfortable with the following scenario: I use Selenium to grab the webpage content (so the browser renders page with javascript things) and then feed [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) with it and navigate it with BeautifulSoup methods. It looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://example.com/"

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")

# Let's find some tables and then print all their rows
for table in page("table"):
    for row in table("tr"):
        print(row)
```

However, I'm not sure that you really need Selenium. The site you are going to parse doesn't seem to rely on JavaScript heavily, so it may me easier just to use simpler solutions like [RoboBrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) (or [mechanize](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/) for python2).

Comment: Just curious, what's the benefit you see from using `BeautifulSoup` if you are already used `Selenium`? Thanks in advance for sharing your view ;)

Comment: @drets, well, I'm not sure that it is optimal solution. I was familiar with BeautifulSoup before I learned about Selenium and it was easier for me not to learn new syntax but use already known one. Also I believe that BeautifulSoup's syntax is very consize, e.g. `page("table")` is better then `page.find_elements_by_tag_name("table")`.

Comment: Thanks that works! In the end a clear case of reading the docs and not a pdf on some website!

Comment: Thanks for explanation, +1 from me!